# RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView- not scrolling to the bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a problem with the `RecyclerView`. Every time I add a new text it freezes and  does not scroll to the bottom in order to show new messages. 
Following is my .xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  ,xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exitChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:text="@string/exitChat"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/statusBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:checked="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="@string/user" />


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/chatBox">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/reyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

   .....
</RelativeLayout>
```

What did I do wrong? is this something to do with the `NestedScrollView`?

Comment: you don't need to use NestedScrollview because RecycleView also scrollable widget

Comment: If you have only `RecyclerView` under `NestScrollView` then remove your `scrollview` there is no need of it.

Comment: you can try this **recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);**